# I want to disable audio events if screen reader is being used

Tags: javascript, html, audio, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm working on children's products and we have audio playback on click, mouseenter  and focus for a lot of navigation and interactive elements for children who can't read.

But if a screen reader or other accessible tool is on this audio can be distracting and get in the way, overlap with the tool's audio and so on.

Is there any standard practice or method of getting around this?

I know I can't really detect if a user is using an accessibility tool but I don't really know what my options are.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a button on the top of the page to disable all sounds and keep the user choice in session.

Answer (score 1):

The WCAG 2 requirement for self playing audio is that if it plays for more than 3 seconds, you must supply a control to pause/stop the audio.

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast

In addition, you should have a mechanism for choosing to not have any sound effects.